# QPython on Android doesn't get imported

Tags: tkinter, pypi, qpython

I'm running QPython on my Android device. Whenever I try to import Tkinter, it says, "no modules found". What is the package name for Tkinter in PyPI? Or where can I download the Tkinter package for QPython?

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter is not installed with QPython, unlike SL4A and Kivy.  You'll have to install it yourself.  There is a pip console among the scripts, so I'd try using that first.

Comment: Thanks.  To clarify your answer for a real noob like me:
To install websocket on the phone:
1) Click the big button
2) Select “run local script”
3) Select “pip_console.py”
4) Type “pip install websocket”

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no Tkinter/tkinter for Python 2.x/3.x on Android. If there is, please elaborate on where you find it and how you install it. Thanks.